# how to replace a specific numbers instead certain numbers

Tags: awk

I have a text file like this

```
ID  
MQ2427D17-01_1_12
MQ2427D17-01_1_1
MQ2427D17-01_1_2
MQ2427D17-01_1_3
MQ2427D17-01_1_4
MQ2427D17-02_2_5
MQ2427D17-02_2_25
MQ2427D17-02_2_1
MQ2427D17-02_2_2
MQ2427D17-02_2_3
MQ2427D17-02_2_4
MQ2427D17-01_1_28
MQ3427D17-01_1_29
MQ3427D17-01_1_1
MQ3427D17-01_1_2
MQ3427D17-01_3_3
MQ3427D17-01_3_30
MQ3427D17-01_3_33
```

I want to change the numbers at the end whenever it is 1 to 13, whenever it is 2 to 14, whenever it is 3 to 15 , whenever it is 4 to 16, whenever it is 5 to 17, whenever it is 6 to 18, whenever it is 7 to 19 , .... whenever it is 12 to 24.

so the output looks like this

```
ID  
MQ2427D17-01_1_24
MQ2427D17-01_1_13
MQ2427D17-01_1_14
MQ2427D17-01_1_15
MQ2427D17-01_1_16
MQ2427D17-02_2_17
MQ2427D17-02_2_25
MQ2427D17-02_2_13
MQ2427D17-02_2_14
MQ2427D17-02_2_15
MQ2427D17-02_2_16
MQ2427D17-01_1_28
MQ3427D17-01_1_29
MQ3427D17-01_1_13
MQ3427D17-01_1_14
MQ3427D17-01_3_15
MQ3427D17-01_3_30
MQ3427D17-01_3_33
```

I was trying to do it with this

```
sed 's/1/13/g' myfile.txt > modified.txt

sed = Stream EDitor
The command string:
s = the substitute command
original = a regular expression describing the number to replace
g = global (i.e. replace all and not just the first occurrence)
myfile.txt = mydata
modified.txt = the output
```

but this will change the number anywhere they are

I don't know why the solution below does not work, for example on this example data

```
ID
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_1
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_2
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_3
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_4
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_5
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_6
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_7
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_8
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_9
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_10
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_11
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_12
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_1
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_2
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_3
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_4
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_5
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_6
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_7
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_8
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_9
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_10
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_11
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_12
```

It should be

```
 ID
 MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_13
 MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_14
 MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_15
 MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_16
 MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_17
 MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_18
 MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_19
 MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_20
 MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_21
 MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_22
 MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_23
 MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_24
 MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_13
 MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_14
 MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_15
 MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_16
 MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_17
 MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_18
 MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_19
 MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_20
 MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_21
 MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_22
 MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_23
 MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_24
```

Comment: This is not at all clear, please do mention your conditions to get expected output more clearly  with examples in your post and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have no condition. I want to replace the number at the end of each line. 1 to 13. 2 to 14 ..... 12 to 24. just look at the second example

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I just added the output for the second example too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} $NF>=1 && $NF<=12{$NF+=12} 1' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {gsub(/\r/,"")} $NF>=1 && $NF<=12{$NF+=12} 1' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} $NF>=1 && $NF<=12{$NF+=12} 1' Input_file
```

After doing troubleshooting with user in chatroom came to know that OP has control M characters(which OP doesn't want to have) so advised OP to remove them by doing `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file` and then run above code.

Comment: I use your solution, it gives me something else, can you join to the chat please ?

Answer (score 4):

From your description, we can observe a pattern: adding 12 to the end-numbers if the end-numbers are below 12. (Here, *end-numbers* refer to the numbers after the last underscore.)

`awk` can accomplish this task.

```
awk -F_ -v OFS=_ '{if($NF <= 12) $NF += 12;}1' myfile.txt >modified.txt
```

Flags:

- `-F_`: input delimiter is `_`
- `-v OFS=_`: one of `awk`'s special variables, denoting the **O**utput **F**ile **S**eperator (aka the output delimiter)

Others:

- `NF`: another one of `awk`'s special variables, denoting the **N**umber of **F**ields
- `$NF`: this will get the variable holding the last field.
- `{...}1`: the `1` at the end tells `awk` to print everything.

I personally wouldn't recommend using `sed` since you'll need to replace 1 with 13, 2 with 14, 3 with 15, (and so on) individually. This makes it a mm... tedious candidate to manhandle. On the other hand, `awk` can perform basic mathematical computations (such as `+12` as you've seen) while still being able to parse input.

Output:

```
ID
MQ2427D17-01_1_24
MQ2427D17-01_1_13
MQ2427D17-01_1_14
MQ2427D17-01_1_15
MQ2427D17-01_1_16
MQ2427D17-02_2_17
MQ2427D17-02_2_25
MQ2427D17-02_2_13
MQ2427D17-02_2_14
MQ2427D17-02_2_15
MQ2427D17-02_2_16
MQ2427D17-01_1_28
MQ3427D17-01_1_29
MQ3427D17-01_1_13
MQ3427D17-01_1_14
MQ3427D17-01_3_15
MQ3427D17-01_3_30
MQ3427D17-01_3_33
```

Comment: this one replace 1 to 13 but does not do anything for 2, 3, 4, ... until 12

Comment: I gave one example data above again , you can see that it does not work

Comment: Hmm... I'm getting the same output as your expected output. What OS and version of bash are you using?

Comment: I am using Mac, I added a second example above with expected output. can you please check

Comment: @Learner "_that it does not work_" please be clear why the solution didn't work.

Comment: when I use the second example, I expect that it replace 1 to 13, 2 to 14, .... 12 to 24. but it only change 1 to 13 and that is all . do you get the second example to the exact output?

Comment: @Learner It works perfectly fine for me. It changes as you've stated, 1 to 13, 2 to 14, and so on up to 12 to 24. Can you try closing the text files, running the script again, then reopening the file?

Comment: one question, if I have 13, 14, 15 ... 24 there already, would it have effect ? I want to also 12 numbers to them too. so that I see the differences

Comment: I closed it and run it again . let me restart my computer to make sure that everything is OK and let you know

Comment: it works just fine for the first example but the second one, no it does not work. it gives the following output `ID
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_13
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_2
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_3
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_4
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_5
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_6
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_7
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_8
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_9
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_22
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_23
MQ3HHD2D17-01_1_12
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_13
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_2
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_3
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_4
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_5
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_6
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_7
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_8
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_9
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_22
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_23
MQ4HHD2D17-01_2_24`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187774/discussion-between-trebuchetms-and-learner).

Comment: I liked your answer too

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution using Perl one-liner

```
perl -pe ' s/(\d+)$/$1<13?$1+12:$1/ge '
```

with inputs.

```
$ perl -pe ' s/(\d+)$/ $1<13 ? $1+12 : $1/ge ' learner.txt
ID
MQ2427D17-01_1_24
MQ2427D17-01_1_13
MQ2427D17-01_1_14
MQ2427D17-01_1_15
MQ2427D17-01_1_16
MQ2427D17-02_2_17
MQ2427D17-02_2_25
MQ2427D17-02_2_13
MQ2427D17-02_2_14
MQ2427D17-02_2_15
MQ2427D17-02_2_16
MQ2427D17-01_1_28
MQ3427D17-01_1_29
MQ3427D17-01_1_13
MQ3427D17-01_1_14
MQ3427D17-01_3_15
MQ3427D17-01_3_30
MQ3427D17-01_3_33

$
```